# “List 'Documents' does not exist at site with url [...]" error on execute querry - but it works on devsite? Are Shared Documents different on devsite?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a sharepoint online provider-hosted (Azure) add-in. It worked properly when debugging and it works properly when I deploy it to my devsite. The problem occurs when I deploy it to any other site - I get the following error :

> List 'Documents' does not exist at site with URL 'https://xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxxxx'

The thing is - I checked this multiple times on multiple sites, the List names are the same as on devsite.

Here are some parts of my Elements.xml, Default.aspx and AppManifest.xml, I have literally no idea what could be causing this but my intuition tells me it could be connected to those lines :

```
  <CustomAction 
            RegistrationType="List"
            RegistrationId="{$ListId:Shared Documents;}"
            Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
            Sequence="10001"
            Title="Invoke &apos;RibbonApprovalAction&apos; action">
```

---

```
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list" Right="FullControl" />
```

---

```
                using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
                {

                    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web,
                    web => web.Title,
                    web => web.CurrentUser,
                    web => web.Lists);

                    List doclist = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

The error occurs at the last line, when I try to execute querry. But like I said, it works perfectly on my devsite. It's as if Shared Documents on devsite were different from Shared Documents on any other site... I don't get it.

Comment: could you try it as `clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");` ?

Comment: I did try it, I also tried putting %20 instead of the space even though it doesn't make any sense and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so if anyone is interested - I found an answer on StackOverflow posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873418/sharepoint-list-does-not-exist-on-the-site-efter-but-it-exists-in-my-code-when-d) posted by user Aarti. I used the list validate function instead of this

```
List doclist = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
```

to get the List instead and now it works.